# Image won't resize to Skeleton container when using mouseover effect

Tags: image, hover, responsive-design, mouseover, image-resizing

I'm using Skeleton to create a responsive website. Normally when the the browser window size changes, the images within each container adjust accordingly, however, I'm having issues with two images that incorporate a mouseover effect.

Here is the HTML. Hovering over the image triggers a replacement image.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="feature" class="eight columns alpha">
<a href="http://swordandplough.com/pages/lookbook" class="cssmouseover" style="background-image: url('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Flag-Lookbook-Link.jpg?3039');"></a>
</div>
  <div id="feature" class="eight columns omega">
<a href="http://swordandplough.com/pages/video" class="cssmouseover" style="background-image: url('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Flag-Video-Link.jpg?3039');"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the mouseover CSS.

```
a.cssmouseover {
display:block;
width:580px;
height:260px;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
background-position:50% 0%;
}
a.cssmouseover:hover {
background-position:50% -100%;
}
```

I've also added the the following div ID in an attempt to get the image to resize correctly, but it isn't working.

```
#feature img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Instead of scaling proportionally, the image height stays the same size and the width gets cropped on either side.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a background image the properties applied to #feature img are not doing anything. You may want to explore using `background-size: cover` and use 2 images for the hover, rather than a sprite. Here is an article with some good documentation.
http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios